# Does a moving average preserve resolution over sum / count quotient in a binary system?

Tags: algorithm, binary, average, moving-average

There are multiple methods for find the average of a set of numbers.

First, the sum / count quotient. Add all values and divide them by the number of values.

Second, the moving average. The function I found in another Stack answer is:

> New average = old average * (n-1)/n + new value /n

This works as long as each value is added to the average one value at a time.

My concern is that the second method is more calculatively complex for my processor to execute, but I also fear that the first method will result in a loss of resolution for data sets that result in large sums. In a 32 bit system, for example, the resolution of a float value stored is reduced automatically as the magnitude of the number grows.

Does a moving average preserve resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"moving average" does not calculate average over large interval.

It smooth data in such way that newer measurements give larger impact, and older measurements weight becomes smaller and smaller.

If you bother about large sums and want to preserve all possible data "bits", consider special methods like [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) algorithm

Comment: Brilliant! I actually implemented something similar to this awhile back...

Comment: > Sum_INT _double integer
> Sum_FLT _float_
>
> Sum_FLT += new_Value
>
> if ( Sum_FLT >= 1 ) {
>      remainder = MOD ( Sum_FLT )
>      new_Value -= remainder
>      Sum_INT += new_Value
>      Sum_FLT = remainder
>}

It stores the whole integer value of the sum in an integer, adds the new number to the float (the running remainder), checks if the float is greater than or equal to one, grabs the whole integer quantity in the float, throws that integer value onto the sum.

Sorry, I'm new here... I don't know what I'm doing haha